# Why is lisa[i_, j_] :> Nothing un-evaluated?

Tags: list-manipulation

*Anyone know how to correct it with minor change?*

**Input**`(i = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}; j = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}; 
(Tuples[lisa[i, j]] /. lisa[i_, j_] :> i/j)/. lisa[i_, j_] :> Nothing`

**Output**`{1, 1/3, 1/5, 1/7, 1/9, 3, 1, 3/5, 3/7, 1/3, 5, 5/3, 1, 5/7, 5/9, 7, \
7/3, 7/5, 1, 7/9, 9, 3, 9/5, 9/7, 1}`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting to see - you replace all `lisa[i_,j_]` by something else, and then you replace `list[i_,j_]` by something again - obviously the second one will not find anything

Comment: @Lucas How can you add `lisa[i_,j_];>Nothing `? I mean by not changing  the first one`Tuples[lisa[i, j]] /. lisa[i_, j_] :> i/j`

Comment: But what do you want to get in the end? Because `list[i_,j_]:>Nothing` will just replace all the elements by `Nothing`, giving an empty list

Comment: How can you add  `i!=j`?

Comment: So you want `Tuples[list[i,j]] /. {lisa[i_, i_] :> Nothing, lisa[i_,j_] :> i/j}`?

Comment: Or `(Tuples[lisa[i, j]] /. lisa[i_, j_] :> i/j) /. (1 -> Nothing)`

Comment: @Lucas Lang your code just didn't work here. Here is the result. `{list[1, 1], list[1, 3], list[1, 5], list[1, 7], list[1, 9], 
 list[3, 1], list[3, 3], list[3, 5], list[3, 7], list[3, 9], 
 list[5, 1], list[5, 3], list[5, 5], list[5, 7], list[5, 9], 
 list[7, 1], list[7, 3], list[7, 5], list[7, 7], list[7, 9], 
 list[9, 1], list[9, 3], list[9, 5], list[9, 7], list[9, 9]}`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, yours seem to work.  Can I use a function to do that? Like `lisa[i_,j_]:>Module[{i!=j},i/j]`

Comment: `Tuples[lisa[i, j] /. lisa[i_, j_] :> Module[{}, i != j; i/j]]` _Why is this not working?_

Comment: `f[i_List, 
   j_List] := (Tuples[lisa[i, j]] /. lisa[x_, y_] :> x/y) /. (1 -> 
     Nothing); 

i = j = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}; 

f[i, j]`

Comment: Or since the function `lisa` is only used as a placeholder, 

`f2[i_List, j_List] = Flatten[Outer[#1/#2 &, i, j] /. (1 :> Nothing)]`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon Can u use `Module` to solve it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99989/discussion-between-bob-hanlon-and-kile).

Comment: @LukasLang _Can I publish your comments as a answer to this question?_

Comment: @kile Sure, feel free to post an answer - the general consensus on this site is that if someone posts solutions in the comments, they do not feel it deserves to be an answer / don't have the time to write one. But others are usually very welcome to convert comments into an answer if they feel that it might be useful (you can always mention that you've taken it from someones comment if you want to give credit).

Comment: @LukasLang Can you please have a look at my answer here? Maybe I have a misunderstanding of your answer. Could you possibly correct it if you find error ?

Comment: @BobHanlon Can you check my answer out here? I am not sure whether I have interpreted your idea correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First of all , special thanks to @LukasLang and @BobHanlon

**Lucas's Method**

### 1st

`i = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}; j = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
Tuples[lisa[i,j]] /. {lisa[i_, i_] :> Nothing, lisa[i_,j_] :> i/j}`

This `lisa[i_, i_] :> Nothing` will delete the circumstance when `i!=j`(Mathematica will automatically interpret `!=` into `≠`)  , which will produce 1 in the output.

`{lisa[i_, i_] :> Nothing, lisa[i_,j_] :> i/j}` will be treated as a whole when `lisa[i_, i_] :> Nothing` and `lisa[i_,j_] :> i/j` will be evaluated simultaneously.

## 2nd

`i = j={1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
Tuples[lisa[i, j]] /. lisa[i_, j_] /; i != j :> i/j /. lisa[i_, i_] :> Nothing`

The other method Lucas provide here is to use `Condition` to make sure  `i!=j` is a constraint here. Fuction `lisa[i_, j_] /; i != j :> i/j` will be evaluated only when `i!=j` happens. After that,  `lisa[i_, i_] :> Nothing` will be evaluated.

**BobHanlon's Method**

## 1st

`i = j={1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
(Tuples[lisa[i, j]] /. lisa[i_, j_] :> i/j) /. (1 -> Nothing)`

Bob's method here is more direct in the output. Since we know know that if `i=j` then the output is will be 1. In order to delete 1 in the output, Bob delete 1 with `1 -> Nothing`. It first produce an output with 1 , `/. (1 -> Nothing)` will definitely delete 1

## 2nd

`f[i_List,j_List] := (Tuples[lisa[i, j]] /. lisa[x_, y_] :> x/y) /. (1 ->       Nothing);

 i = j = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};

f[i, j]`

I think `f[i_List,  j_List]` can be substituted for `f[i_,j_]`. Cause it will generate the same result. In the second method here Bob choose function `f` as the highest rank function in this code.

## 3rd

`i = j = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};

f[i_List, j_List] = Flatten[Outer[#1/#2 &, i, j] /. (1 :> Nothing)]`

Or since the function lisa is only used as a placeholder, #1 and #2 simply mean that #1 and #2 is a arbitrary  number of `{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}`